# DataGridView Winforms: FullRowSelect current cell still visible

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have one DGV with selection mode set to full row select and selection backcolor set to yellow.

Although full row is selected but still I can see(and move) the selected cell because of a border around it.

How to get rid of that.

EDIT:It happens when TAB is used when a row is selected.

Answer (score 1):

try using

```
StandardTab = true
```

in the dgv properties